How to smooth and remove noisy stripes in Power Spectrum?
I have the following power spectrum of acoustic data over multiple sensors. I used Fast Fourier Transform to estimate periodogram at each sensor. I wonder if there are techniques to clean, smooth, and remove the noisy stripes in the power spectrum.

Noisy stripes across the channel number or across the frequency axis?

but these "noisy stripes" are a significant part of your signal. With which signal processing reasoning can you remove them? That just really feels wrong. "You see, my company's financial reports look much nicer when I exclude all expenses" is a comparison that comes to mind :D

(note that I think that you probably have a point – but it makes more sense to process your signal such to get these things that you do want to know instead of deleting what you don't want from a lossy processing step. But to help you with how to achieve that, we really need to know what you need from the signal, and why you think the "noisy lines" (not even sure which ones you're referring to – lines are not typically noise) are ignorable.)

@Marcus Müller The above data shows power spectrum for inflow along pipe. High at noise sensors (0 - 2000) indicates high inflow rate. I wonder if there is a way to remove noisy stripes over frequency to make the signal at low frequency clearer. I tried to remove the mean over frequency from each sensor but it doesn't help.

I don't see "noisy stripes"; I see signal! That's the thing – you say "noisy stripes", but these seem to me to be very important information. How do you know it's OK to ignore them? Other than that, to remove high frequencies, you apply a low-pass filter (but judging from your nickname, you probably knew that already)

Maybe could you actually describe what you want to see instead of what you don't want to see? Maybe make a circle around it in your plot? It might just be that I'm totally misunderstanding you.

@MarcusMüller I may have had the wrong interpretation from the start, but I was interpreting his concern as potentially being artifacts due to the nature of using an unmodified periodogram, which could be solved by another spectral analysis technique. I could be wrong on that assumption, though.

@Baddioes hm that makes sense, as well.

@SignalProcessing could you edit your question to make it clearer what your problem is? As it currently is, I'm not even sure which lines you mean, as there's multiple direction in which one could see lines. If you're looking for a better signal analysis method, as Baddioes assumes, then you'll have to tell us more about your signal – and again, what specifically you want to see (instead of just what you don't want to see)
